# How to access to laravel routing resource methods?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am using laravel to have access to my database. I have used the command `php artisan make:controller CategoriesController --resource` in the terminal to create a class where I can access different methods in one route.

The routing code for the class is: `Route::apiResource("categories", CategoriesController::class);`. With */categories* I can get to the index() method (via get), where I can show my table values. But I do not know how I can use other methods. For example I have created `test()` with a simple `return ["Result"=>"Working"]`.

I have tried /categories/test /categoriestest /categories%test but I can not show the result from test().

Simple routing works fine when I use specific routes for every method, but I want to make a more clear code so I would like to use the --resource to only have one route.

Comment: For custom controller methods you need to add explicit routes, such as `Route::get('categories', [CategoriesController::class, 'test']);`

Comment: Please read through the [relevant documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)

Comment: Resource controller and route only handle specific routes and their methods. see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller). Any other methods added would need a routing method. or you may write some code to override laravel's default behavior.

Comment: The `apiResource` method will only produce routes for `index`, `store`, `show`, `update` and `destroy`. As mentioned above, you will need to add you're own `Route` for any custom methods. [Route::apiResource() docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#api-resource-routes).